# Why does one button overlay but the other doesn't?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a carousel and I have a next and previous button that is supposed to be used by the user to iterate through the images in said carousel. My goal is to have the next and prev buttons overlay ontop on the images, since that's how I'm specified to have it, the only problem is for some reason, my right button is overlaying, but my left button is not. They are both styled under the same class so I'm not sure why one is overlaying and the other is not.

Here's my code

```css
/* CSS  */

.carousel {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.carouselimages {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Innercontainer {
  background-color: lawngreen;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.imageslides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.imagecontainers {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.carouselbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carouselbutton img {
  width: 25px;
}

.carouselbutton--left {
  left: 5px;
}

.carouselbutton--right {
  right: 5px;
}

.carouselnav {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <button class="carouselbutton carouselbutton--left">
         <img src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Icons/back.svg" alt="navicons">
       </button>
  <div class="Innercontainer">
    <ul class="imagecontainers">
      <li class="imageslides">
        <img class="carouselimages" src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Images/Banner1.png" alt="Banner1">
      </li>
      <li class="imageslides">
        <img class="carouselimages" src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Images/Banner2.png" alt="Banner2">
      </li>
      <li class="imageslides">
        <img class="carouselimages" src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Images/Banner3.png" alt="Banner3">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="carouselbutton carouselbutton--right">
          <img src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Icons/next.svg" alt="navicons">
       </button>
</div>
```

This is what I get:
[image: How it looks]

Comment: Positioned elements are stacked "in order of appearance in the HTML" when `z-index` is not specified; see [Stacking without the z-index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index). Also see [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Answer (score 1):

Add a z-index to your buttons:

```
.carouselbutton{
      position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
      background: transparent;
      border: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your button is already positioned (absolute). But you need to set the depth of the element, just like layering. use the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) css .

```
.carouselbutton{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;

  z-index: 1;
}
```

Please use lowest possible value for **z-index**, which you can start by trying to use 1, then 2, then 3, and so on (sequentially) until it fits on the expected layer.

The bad habit for a lot of programmer is to put value in **z-index** in crazy big number like **999, 9999, 10000, 9999999**. which is bad practice especially if you are writing a library meant to be used by others

Answer (score 0):

Move your left button after the `carousel` and it shall work.

```css
/* CSS  */

.carousel {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.carouselimages {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Innercontainer {
  background-color: lawngreen;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.imageslides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.imagecontainers {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.carouselbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carouselbutton img {
  width: 25px;
}

.carouselbutton--left {
  left: 5px;
}

.carouselbutton--right {
  right: 5px;
}

.carouselnav {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="Innercontainer">
    <ul class="imagecontainers">
      <li class="imageslides">
        <img class="carouselimages" src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Images/Banner1.png" alt="Banner1">
      </li>
      <li class="imageslides">
        <img class="carouselimages" src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Images/Banner2.png" alt="Banner2">
      </li>
      <li class="imageslides">
        <img class="carouselimages" src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Images/Banner3.png" alt="Banner3">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Move the button to HERE -->
  <button class="carouselbutton carouselbutton--left">
    <img src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Icons/back.svg" alt="navicons">
  </button>
  <button class="carouselbutton carouselbutton--right">
    <img src="Assets/Carousel - Task 2 Assets/Icons/next.svg" alt="navicons">
  </button>
</div>
```